# .zip ibm mq source

Tags: download, ibm-mq

I am searching for the ibm mq .zip documentation.

I need it for installing t on my machine to have the descriptions of all the methods and calss of it.

Where can I download it ?
Spasiba

Answer (score 0):

The 'WMQ Library' is available at this location http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/library/index.html

From here you can either look at the online InfoCenters; or you can download them to use offline.

The JavaDoc for the Java clients is also laid down on disk when you install. So for example on Windows - C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\doc

Note there is an InfoCenter that gives information about using WAS-WMQ together - the Product Connectivity InfoCenter - this has downloads in PDF and EPUB format for the scenarios.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/prodconn/v1r0m0/index.jsp